# How to replace text infile with regular Expression?

Tags: visual-build-professional

I want to replace a version number by a more current one (i.e. getting it from SVN, which is working fine). For testing purposes I try to replace what I find with something simple, but not even this is working.

This regular expression looks fine (e.g. tested in https://regex101.com/) and correctly matches my version number.

RegEx:

```
([1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.([1-9][0-9]|[0-9])\.([1-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])
```

Text to match (that is not matched):

> Title="MyTitle 1.0.0"

According to https://regex101.com/ this should work. But Visual Build cannot find any match and no replacement is done.

I can confirm that file access is working, because Visual Build adds the text "error while replacing" to the specified file.

[image]

I'm using Visual Build Professional v10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what's wrong with your existing regex, but when I've had to do similar replacements I've tried to manufacture a replacement strategy that is a little different - basically to keep the regex as simple as possible. You could try something like this:

Text or regex to find:

`Title=.*`

e.g., just match the correct line of the file. Don't worry about the existing version number values.

Text to replace matches with:

`Title="MyTitle %v1%.%v2%.%v3%"`

I'm assuming you have three macros `v1`, `v2`, `v3` for your version number parts. If you have one for the app title you could obviously insert that there too.

Comment: Simplifying my regex was the hint that I need. Since I cannot guarantee that the title will stand on its own in the line (it's a XAML), I came up with this, which matches the Title attribute, the first quotation mark and anything up to the next quotation mark: `Title=".+?(?=")`